# Repairing a loose guitar bridge

Tags: acoustic-guitar, repair, bridge

Today I got a 'crescent' 3/4 size with a loose bridge.

How would I fix it?

Comment: Read this answer to a similar question [link](http://music.stackexchange.com/a/30402/16897)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend finding a repair person to fix this.  If you don't have the proper tools, you might break it more.

But, if you **truly** want to try, [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=27yHx5XqYDY) video might help.  He basically takes off the strings, bridge, and string pegs.  Then, he glues the bridge back on, after taking the old glue and crud off.  This guy IS a professional who has obviously done this before.  I recommend against trying, go find a repair person.